# Optimizing a Hive SQL query with Spark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I have a complex SQL query that I use to get data in Hadoop Hive.

I have started reading about Spark and PySpark. There appear to be performance improvements with those tools. But since I still need to get my data from Hive, Spark is irrelevant, right? In other words, if I have to query Hive for my data, any performance improvements I gain from Spark would only come from transformations I apply to the data after retrieving it from Hive.

Am I understanding these technologies correctly?

Comment: Correct. So ```select ... from x where ...``` would be faster in hive, BUT if you add more tables, joins etc. Then in most cases you can make them much faster in spark.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, it depends on your Hive execution engine, file format and partitioning/bucketing. It's not simply Hive vs Spark. For example, reading a CSV file with Spark would require more resources than a partitioned, Snappy compressed Parquet or ORC table in Hive

Data format aside, if Spark and Hive queries run in YARN, they'd occupy approximately the same resources to compute the data, although Spark would allow you to do more with the resultset since it is programmatically defined

You could also make Hive use Spark rather than Mapreduce as the execution engine, or Tez as another option

Spark only uses the Hive Metastore to lookup data, so the performance is also different on which database engine/client you are using (Spark vs Presto vs direct JDBC or Thrift)